# Android Studios Not Showing Certain Chinese Characters

Tags: character-encoding, android-studio, chinese-locale

I have a text file encoded as UTF-8 containing Chinese character which opens fine in Notepad++, however when opened in Android Studio some of the characters are replaced with "□" indicating they are missing. (Android Studio IDE is also set to UTF-8).

Here are some of the character which are missing

(U+2A6A9)
 (U+299A2)

It seem to be any character which are in Unicode Block CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_Unified_Ideographs,_Extension_B_(Part_1_of_7)

I have also visited the link above on my Android tablet(KitKat) which also doesn't display these characters.

Comment: The font may simply not have those characters.

Comment: I'm using Consolas which I have used in Eclipse were to showed up fine

Comment: Consolas doesn't have those characters. They have been substituted from another font. Check Android Studio's font settings, there should be an option for a secondary font – pick something that has all needed characters.

Comment: Same problem here, someone said that change the font under File>Settings> Appearance & Behavior >Appearance > Override default fonts by > some font like  simsun or Microsoft Yahei will fix this problem. But it failed for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Android Studio has fixed this bug in version 2.2 and above. And it is proved by [issue 116668](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=116668).

[image: Android studio Chinese bug]